# MVC3 ActionName attribute, its behaviour and effects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

While reading about mcv3 I came across an attribute name called `[ActionName]`. It actually gives a new name to the action method. I tested a scenario which made me think; how are the internals working. When I have the following two action methods in my controller class

```
[ActionName("Test")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return View();
}
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
      return View();
}
```

I thought this will end up in some kind of infinite loop or will give some ambiguity exception. But the same works fine and the second method is called when i give this url `http://mysite:1234/mycontroller`

What made MVC engine to choose the second method and not the first?

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Phil Haack has a post on this matter: [How a method becomes an action](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx)

In short: the ControllerActionInvoker uses reflection to find a method matches the action name.

The ActionNameAttribute redefines the name of the method.

Also be aware that the name of your View matches the ActionName, not the MethodName: the method Index will search for a view with the name "Test"

Comment: ok, Excellent post. From the post what I get is, the magician is the ControllerActionInvoker. This will read the data (from key "action") from the  route data dictionary.It will get a string value. And then it will search for the ActionName first and then the Method Name.

Comment: @thinkmmk It will not look for the method, it looks for the `action`. Not using the ActionNameAttribute results in: method = action

Comment: @AndrewF If I dont have any ActionName attribute over my methods, then what I guess is ControllerActionInvoker will look for Methods name through reflection in my controller class. or does mvc puts action name attribute by itself if not present?

Comment: @thinkmmk Yes. `By default, the ControllerActionInvoker uses reflection to find a public method on a class that derives from Controller which has the same name (case insensitive) as the current action.`

Answer (score 8):

This is the magic of the [Routing engine](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs). Somewhere within the global.asax.cs file there would be routing patterns defined, mostly which defaults to

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",                                              // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
          );
```

This is a routing pattern defined for your application. The action name attribute maps to the 'action' parameter within the parameter collection (3rd parameter for MapRoute).

In your case if you map the action 'Index' to method 'Test'. It should call Test() method. I am not sure whether it is still calling Index() for you. In fact the routing engine does not care about the method name if it finds the ActionName attribute over your public method.

Comment: Hi Chandermani,
Thanks and Yes, I have the above lines in my global.asax file. And I edited my question, Yes it calls the Test() method.
So what I understand from your explanation is that, this is the magic of Routing Engine. And it will give preference to the ActionName attribute rather than the actual method name if it finds duplicate names. One more thing, where is this decission taking place i.e inside the Routing phase or in Control Action phase of the lifecycle?

Comment: If you look at the route new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }. The routing engine decides, the controller, the action (hence the method on controller), and then the control is passed to the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

ActionNameAttribute it represents an attribute that is used for the name of an action. If it is not present the name of the method is used.